# How to set an activity whitelist for UIActivityViewController rather than a blacklist?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

Most examples of using `UIActivityViewController` show how to exclude activity types but they don't show how to only specify wanted types.

**For example,**

I only want ***email*** and ***messages*** to be the displayed activities. The init method of `UIActivityViewController` has a parameter called `applicationActivities` which is an **array of UIActivity**.

This implies to me that passing an array of `UIActivity` rather than nil would be setting a whitelist. It seems that populating this array would achieve what I want. Is my assumption correct? If so, what are the classes for ***email*** and ***messages***.

**Question:**

How do I instantiate instances of them? Or more generally, how do I figure out the class of any of the standard activity types and instantiate them?

Comment: That argument is a lots of UIActivity items to shown in addition to any other activities. There is no "whitelist" function.

Comment: I'm really surprised that I can't find more references to this. It seems logical to me that a whitelist would be more desirable than a blacklist.